# UWP + MvvmLight - ViewModelLocator defined as App.xaml resource is returning Access Denied error in Design Mode

Tags: xaml, mvvm, win-universal-app, mvvm-light, viewmodellocator

I'm building UWP app with MVVMLight and I have problem with my ViewModelLocator in Design Mode.

I created ViewModelLocator:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
  public MainPageViewModel Main =>ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();


  static ViewModelLocator()
  {
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainPageViewModel>();

    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMainPageDataService, DesignMainPageDataService>();
    }
    else
    {         
      SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMainPageDataService, MainPageDataService>();              
    }
  }
}
```

And then I declared it as App resource:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"></viewModels:ViewModelLocator>  
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

It should work now and I should have possibility to define MainPageViewModel as MainPage DataContext but Intellisense is underlining

```
<viewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator"></viewModels:ViewModelLocator>
```

with error

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

I noticed that when I'm not using ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic property it works properly and I can see design data at MainPage.
Something like this works:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
  public MainPageViewModel Main =>ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainPageViewModel>();


  static ViewModelLocator()
  {
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainPageViewModel>();

    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IMainPageDataService, DesignMainPageDataService>();
  }
}
```

Have you any ideas to resolve this weird problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "when I'm not using `ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic` property"? What is `ViewModelLocator` code like in this case? Are you still registering `DesignMainPageDataService` at design time? Based on your info so far, this service the most probable cause for your issue.

Comment: I meant that any usage of `ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic` in `ViewModelLocator` constructor is causing this error.

Comment: Sorry, nothing comes to mind and I can't reproduce the issue. If you haven't done so already, try rebuilding the solution and restarting Visual Studio.

Comment: Everything works fine for me. Consider providing the code for your services.

Comment: Problem is that even without registering my services it doesn't work. (I checked case when I left `if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)` empty - still access denied error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... it was something wrong with my environment. I checked it on another machine and it works flawless.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and finally fixed it by using the native UWP `Windows.ApplicationModel.DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled` and now all is working well.

Additionally, I am in the process of switching to Prism, unclear if this is a VS/Blend issue, or an MVVMLight issue, but slowing finding more items I find easier to use and more robust about Prism 6, such as its Validation for example.